# Problemas de retorno en Python

Tags: python, bucles, while

Estoy desarrollando un ejercicio en el que hay una función que lee un número y si este es divisible entre 2 devuelve como resultado "Positivo"; lo desarrollo y con el número 8 me da False cuando debería ser true ya que 8%2 = 0 pero me devuelve true. A continuación mi código.

```
    def is_power_of_two(n):
    # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
    while n % 2 == 0:
        n = 0
        break
    # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
    if n == 1:
        return True
    return False


print(is_power_of_two(0))  # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1))  # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8))  # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9))  # Should be False
```

Me gustaría saber qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal, muchas gracias.

Comment: Dentro del `while`, asignas `n = 0` si el número es par. Por lo que con 8, número par, te pone `n = 0`, y por lo tanto, devuelve False. Creo que lo que querías en tu while era poner `n = n / 2`

Comment: Y qué debería hacer en su lugar?

Comment: Pues se supone que tienes que dividir `n` entre 2, no? Pues pon eso. dentro del while pon `n = n / 2`, y quita el `break`.

Comment: si quito el break la consola no devuelve nada y poniendo `n = n / 2` con 8 sigue dandome el mismo error, la verdad son muy complicado y hasta confusos esos return true y return false, podrías explicarme de manera más clara?

Answer (score 1):

Según el nombre de la función, y los comentarios que hay en el código, lo que hace la función es decirte si el número pasado es una potencia de 2 o no.

En tu código, hay algunos errores de lógica. En tu `while`, por ejemplo, tienes:

```py
while n % 2 == 0:
    n = 0
    break
```

Eso lo único que hace es que si el número es par (`n % 2 == 0`), entra en el bucle y asigna `n = 0`. Luego el `break` termina el bucle, esto en sí no te sirve de mucho para saber si el número es una potencia de 2. De hecho, sin el `break` sería bucle infinito porque `0 % 2 == 0` es `True`.

En tu while quieres:

```py
while n % 2 == 0:
    n = n / 2
```

Ahora, mientras el número sea par, lo dividirá en 2, y guardará el resultado, si sigue siendo par, lo divide en dos, etc. Hasta que sea impar.

Lo demás estaría bien, aunque el final puedes reducirlo, y quitar los if, si pones: `return n == 1`

---

Dicho esto, la función no hace lo que tú dices que debería hacer:

> estoy desarrollando un ejercicio en el que hay una funcion que lee un número y si este es divisible entre 2 devuelve como resultado "Positivo"

Para hacer eso, solo necesitas comprobar lo que tienes en el while, y devolver "Positivo" en caso de ser par:

```py
def divisible_entre_dos(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 'Positivo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Para saber si un número es divisible por dos, basta comprobar que el resto de la división sea cero.

Con eso el código se reduce a:

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
    # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
    return n % 2 == 0
```

**Demo**

```
print(is_power_of_two(0))  # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1))  # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8))  # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9))  # Should be False
```

produce

```
True
False
True
False
```